# add 2 legends in a geopandas graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I have a map of Mexico with the number of murders by state the map looks like this[image]

and that I used is this

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
 ax.set_title('Feminicidios, 2019', 
             pad = 20, 
             fontdict={'fontsize':20, 'color': 'black'})
gdf.plot(column='feminicidio', cmap='YlOrRd', ax=ax, zorder=5,legend=True,
        legend_kwds={'label': "Feminicidios por Entidad Federativa",'orientation': "horizontal"})
ax.axis('off')
plt.savefig('Feminicidios.png')
```

I Would like to ad a new legend or text box with the top 3 states.

PS Im using geopandas.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the targeted rows with `.nlargest()` and plot it on the same `axis`.

```
# first plot
gdf.plot(column='feminicidio', cmap='YlOrRd', ax=ax, zorder=5,legend=True,
    legend_kwds={'label': "Feminicidios por Entidad Federativa",
    'orientation': "horizontal"})
# select 3 rows with most values, then plot.
gdf.nlargest(3, "feminicidio", keep='first').plot(column='feminicidio', 
    cmap='YlOrRd', ax=ax, zorder=5, legend=True,
    legend_kwds={'label': "3 most values", 'orientation': "horizontal"})
```

For reference, see [nlargest](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html)